# Why my app crash when i refreshing the fragment inside the same fragment on button click listner

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment, refresh

I want refresh my fragment when I click on button which inside in this same fragment. I tried some code but when I click on button my app automatically crash.

I try these codes

```
Fragment frg =null;

frg=getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(getFragmentTag(4));

final FragmentTransaction ft =

getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

 ft.detach(frg);

 ft.attach(frg);

ft.commit();
```

And I try this for getting the tags of fragment because I'm using ViewPager.
And I'm Using Androidx Libraries.

My code is this for getting tag.

```
public String getFragmentTag(int pos){

 return "android:switcher:"+R.id.view_pager_main+":"+pos;

    }
```

[image: my app crash log is this]

[image: main line where showing crash]

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem just using this

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(FragmenViews.this).attach(FragmentViews.this).commit();
```